# Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Given this code sample:

```
CGFloat a = 1;
CGFloat b = 2;
CGFloat c = fabsf(a-b);
```

The current Xcode beta compiler gives me this warning:

```
Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see, the code works with a plain `float` type. And when I hunted for the definition of `CGFloat`, I found this:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

So `CGFloat` is now actually a `double`, hence the warning.

Comment: how to fix that warning?

Comment: Simply use `fabs` instead of `fabsf`.

Comment: `CGFloat` is still `float` if you are compiling for a 32-bit device, which includes iPhone 5, iPhone 4s, iPad 2, ...

Comment: Since iOS11 is coming soon, less useful, but I still feel like asking: what's the best approach here for CGFLoat? Use `#if defined` in the code as well?

Comment: If you have code where that matters, I guess I would introduce a `CGFloatRound` function that would use an `#if` to hide the difference.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `fabs` instead of `fabsf`.

[Link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4464)