# source code of Telegram iOS app could'not run on Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, telegram

I have download the code source of Telegram app on their website:https://telegram.org/apps#source-code , when I open it(the project) by Xcode 6.4., there is an one error

[image]

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897956/absolute-value-function-fabsf-given-an-argument-of-type-double-but-has-param

Answer (score 0):

As explained here 
[Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897956/absolute-value-function-fabsf-given-an-argument-of-type-double-but-has-param)

So CGFloat is now actually a double, hence the warning.

Comment: what i need to change

Answer (score 0):

Edit: that the opposite of my inital answer, so I correct: fabsf is expecting a float , and not a double. So just replace fabsf with fabs which expect a double:

```
    if ((fabs(toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]) >= t) || (fabs(previous2Values[idx] - previousValues[idx]) >= t) {
```

Comment: not working . now i am getting an other error in same line."Taking the absolute value of unsigned type 'bool ' has no effect"

Comment: I've just downloaded the sourcecode and was able to compile. There are another fabsf that needs also to be changed in fabs and then it works

Comment: but i am not able to complie

Comment: can you give your skype id , need you help

Comment: can you help me on that issue

Comment: @jace really do what I've said, replace fabsf with fabs. I've tried to run telegraph, and there are other libraries that haves issues so I don't want to spent my all day on this helping you, sorry

Comment: thanks Tomsoft .that error is gone but i am not able to compile http://imgur.com/k0GiZVo  see error here. showing one error but when i am clicking nothing details is coming

Comment: I can't correct all the problem of the compilation of this app (but btw I would appreciate that you mark the question as answered!)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fabsf` to `std::abs`

Import `#import <cmath>`

Enjoy !